# how to copy content of file to another file with deleting some lines in a TXT file based on some strings with python

Tags: python, if-statement, openfiledialog, read-write

i have this python script that open a file dialog and select a text file than copy its content to another file,  what i need to do before i copy to the next file is to delete several lines based on some strings that are predefined in the script.

the problem is that the file is copied as it is without deleting anything.

**can anyone help me to solve this issue??**

## OPenDirectory.py

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

import Tkinter
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import tkFileDialog


def readWrite():
    unwanted = set(['thumbnails', 'tikare', 'cache'])
    mypath = "C:\Users\LT GM\Desktop/"

    Tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
    in_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(initialdir = mypath, filetypes=[('text files', ' TXT ')])

    files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
    for file in files:
        if file.split('.')[1] == 'txt':
            outputFileName = 'Sorted-' + file
            with open(mypath + outputFileName, 'w') as w:
                with open(mypath + '/' + file) as f:
                    for l in f:
                        if l != unwanted:
                            print l
                            w.write(l)
    in_path.close()
if __name__== "__main__":
    readWrite()
```

## ChangedScipt

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Tkinter
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import tkFileDialog


def readWrite():
    unwanted = set(['thumbnails', 'tikare', 'cache'])
    mypath = "C:\Users\LT GM\Desktop/"

    Tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
    in_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(initialdir = mypath, filetypes=[('text files', ' TXT ')])

    files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
    for file in files:
        if file.split('.')[1] == 'txt':

            if file.strip() in unwanted:
                continue
                outputFileName = 'Sorted-' + file
                with open(mypath + outputFileName, 'w') as w:
                    with open(mypath + '/' + file) as f:
                        for l in f:
                            if l != unwanted:
                                print l
                                w.write(l)
    in_path.close()
if __name__== "__main__":
    readWrite()
```

Comment: Your `mypath` needs to be written correctly: `r"C:\Users\LT GM\Desktop"`. And if you're going to manipulate filepaths, please use `os.path.join` instead of adding strings yourself

Comment: i add r to the path as you said but still nothing happen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
blacklist = set(['thumbnails', 'quraan', 'cache'])

with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() in blacklist: continue  # if you want to match the full line
        # if any(word in line for word in blacklist): continue  # if you want to check if a word exists on a line
        outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: based on your code i changed mine but nothing happen  i will edit my question and add the changed script .. take a look